# Can I explicitly invoke property destructors so that I can see which one causes problems?

Tags: debugging, c++11, destructor, explicit-destructor-call

I guess this is a really nasty issue - seems like one of the property destructors of my class creates deadlock. Property destructors are called automatically after class destructor. And I'd like to call them manually and make a log entry after every single one succeeds.

The problem only occurs on devices, where debugger can't be used, so I am using log instead.

```
Client::~Client() {
    // Stops io service and disconnects sockets
    exit();
    LOG("io_service stopped"<<endl);
    // Destroy IO service
    io_.~io_service();
    LOG("io_service destroyed"<<endl);
}
```

But the code above actually causes exception, because the `~io_service()` gets called **twice**.

So is there a way to do this properly? If not, what's an alternative to debugging destructors?

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to do similar thing is using [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html).

Comment: You either have destructor and it gets called automatically, or have a regular function and call it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't alter the compiler behaviour like that. the compiler will augment the destructor to destruct nested objects.

What you can do is to declare `io` as a pointer and allocate it dynamically with `new`. then call `delete io` and monitor what happens there.

Other solution is just to put a breakpoint on the `io` destructor and follow what happens there upon destruction. this is probably the best idea.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll just convert suspicious properties to pointers then. Because, as I said, the problem does not happen on devices where I can use debugger.